# OAuth2 Client with Credential prompt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I understand the different flows and process in OAuth, but am hitting my head against a wall trying to figure out how to achieve one piece of the puzzle.

So, the first step my (ASP .Net Core MVC App) needs to do is present a popup window to the user to allow them to enter their username and password for the third party API I am aiming to consume. I then need to capture the response sent back from the third party authentication server which should contain my authorization code, which I then need to use with each subsequent call to the API...

This is the bit I am struggling with. the presentation of the third party server authentication dialog and the capture of the response including the token.

Any pointers?

-- EDIT --
I am using IdentityModel and can see the functionality I think I need in the OidcClient classes but these are for OpenID compliant interfaces (as far as I can see) and the API I am trying to consume is not an OpenID one... or am I missing something obvious? When I try and use this class I get errors relating to 'DiscoveryDocument' not being found... which I assume is an OpenID thing...

Comment: It's still not clear what you are struggling with. I'd suggest you to read more about [OAuth2 and OIDC](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/big_picture.html) and may be try some [quickstarts](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/0_overview.html) using identityServer4, for example. Just to understand better what you really need

Comment: Hi @AndrewSilver. Yeah sorry maybe my post wasn't terribly helpful. What I need is really simple - I need to understand how to open a browser window to my Authorization URL (the third party API Authorization URL) to allow the user to log in, and then capture the server response which will include my token. All this happens from within my MVC App, so I am assuming it needs to open in a opo-up browser window....

Comment: what you described in your question is [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#protocol-diagram). But you don't need to open those URLs manually, you just need to use some libraries that implement OAuth2/OIDC, such as mentioned [IdentityModel](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), if we are talking about client libraries

Comment: Ok, so when I use Postman to do this, I specify the Authorization endpoint (https://api.channeladvisor.com/oauth2/authorize), at which point I am presented with a browser popup asking me for my credentials. Only when I enter these does Postman then get the relevant tokens... This is the bit I am trying to replicate. I obviously don't want to store or process user credentials within my app as this is precisely what OAuth was supposed to avoid isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you call the /authorize endpoint you get redirected to the login Page where you can input your credentials.

DiscoveryDocument sounds like the /.well-known/openid-configuration endpoint

Do I understand it right, that you are trying this: https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html#requesting-a-token-using-the-authorization-code-grant-type